# ImportError: cannot import name process (Twisted)

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.1, and I remember installing Python some time ago (I can't remember why, given that Mac OS X comes with it). For some reason Twisted wasn't installed, so I installed Zope and Twisted.

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

The problem is, when I run this code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory,Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "a client connected"

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor().run
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mattieman/Desktop/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 52, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 53, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import process, _signals
ImportError: cannot import name process
```

So I took a look in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet`

...and it appears that `process.py` is missing.

What do I do?

There seem to be other files missing as well, like `_baseprocess.py`

I used `setup3.py`, if it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Python 2.6.  You shouldn't use `setup3.py`.  You also shouldn't ever use a distutils `setup.py`-type script to install Python libraries into OS paths (like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/`).

You may have a randomly corrupted Twisted installation on your system now (OS X itself ships with a copy of Twisted).  Or you may just have some garbage in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted` that you need to clean up.  It's difficult to say which (which is why you should never use `setup.py` to install things - it leaves a big mess).

After you clean up that mess (I can't give you many tips on how to do this apart from "reinstall your OS X", sorry), you have a few options:

- Use the version of Twisted distributed with your OS.  Don't try to install a different version.
- Treat your home directory as a simpler "virtual environment" and run `setup.py install --user` (`--user` tells it to leave its mess inside `~/.local` where at least it won't ruin your OS install).
- Create a virtualenv and install a new version of Twisted there

Of these, you probably want to go with virtualenv.

Also note that you shouldn't run `setup3.py` unless you're trying to install Twisted for Python 3.  And if you're trying to do that then I'll warn you that only part of Twisted is ported - and it's a very small part.  For example, it's not process support (hence the import error you're getting).

Comment: setup.py tells me that I don't have gcc-4.0. How do I tell it to use the version I have (simply  called gcc in /usr/bin)?

Comment: I found twisted!! It's at this path though: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted